# Android Studio, app will not run without crashing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

I am trying to make a very simple app in Android Studio, written in Java, for my first app project. I do not have a lot of code written at the moment but every time the app tries to run it 'stops working' and will never open.

I am not positive I am looking in the correct part of Logcat for the error, but this is what I believe Logcat is telling me.

```
2018-10-10 17:21:03.291 11777-20641/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
 Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
```

And this is all the code for my project (almost nothing)

```
Button rollButton = findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
TextView numberRoll = findViewById(R.id.numberRoll);
SeekBar amountSeek = findViewById(R.id.amountSeek);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random ran = new Random();
            ran.nextInt(amountSeek.getProgress());
            numberRoll.setText(ran.toString());
        }

    });
}
```

}

If that is the correct error then it looks like it is an issue with space on the emulator or something. But I do not know how to resolve this issue.

Any help?

Comment: For me it looks like a random crash unrelated to your code. Try to remove everything besides setContentView from your Activity and replace layout XML with simplified version (just FrameLayout with background, probably)

Comment: Try initialize your object views in oncreate or on resume method. Have Your seekbar value in the xml layout? What emulator are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Move below lines to onCreate function after defining the layout file

```
Button rollButton = findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
TextView numberRoll = findViewById(R.id.numberRoll);
SeekBar amountSeek = findViewById(R.id.amountSeek);
```

You are calling the Resources before defining the resource file. This is the function that define the resource file.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Your code should be

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button rollButton = findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
TextView numberRoll = findViewById(R.id.numberRoll);
SeekBar amountSeek = findViewById(R.id.amountSeek);

rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        ran.nextInt(amountSeek.getProgress());
        numberRoll.setText(ran.toString());
    }

});
}
```

or if you like it

```
Button rollButton;
TextView numberRoll;
SeekBar amountSeek;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

rollButton = findViewById(R.id.rollButton);
numberRoll = findViewById(R.id.numberRoll);
amountSeek = findViewById(R.id.amountSeek);

rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        ran.nextInt(amountSeek.getProgress());
        numberRoll.setText(ran.toString());
    }

});
}
```

And make sure the ID's are all set in you xml file.

Just put the dot after R.id. and wait for Android studio to show dropdown list of all id's from your resource file. This way you could prevent typos.